# Algorithm in JavaScript to Merge Two Strings

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

Hoping to learn better ways to solve this algorithm. The input consists of two strings.

Input - example 1:

```
var a = 'abc'
var b = 'def'
```

Expected Output

```
mergedString = 'adbecf';
```

My solution:

```
var a = 'abc';
var b = 'efg';

function mergeStr(a, b) {
  var aArr = a.split('');
  var bArr = b.split('');
  var newStr = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < aArr.length; i++) {
    newStr += aArr[i] + bArr[i];
  }
}

mergeStr(a, b);
```

The solution works for the input example above. But I was stuck when the second input values were given to me which is:

```
var a = 'ab';
var b = 'efg';
```

The expected output is:

```
aebfg
```

LOL since I was being timed I came up with the following junk. I just added an if statement to deal with the exact use case I was given. Obviously this solution is junk. I would really like to see what others would do.

```
function mergeStr(a, b) {
  var aArr = a.split('');
  var bArr = b.split('');
  var newStr = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < aArr.length; i++) {
    newStr += aArr[i] + bArr[i];
  }

  if (a.length < b.length) {
    newStr += b[2];
  }

  console.log(newStr);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access each string character like an array, you don't need to use split them to do this.

My solution uses the ternary operator:

```
function merge( str1, str2 ) {
    let merged = "";
    let max = str1.length > str2.length ? str1.length : str2.length;
    for ( let i = 0; i < max; i++ ) {
        merged += ( str1[i] ? str1[i] : "" ) + ( str2[i] ? str2[i] : "" );
    }
    return merged;
}

// prints acbd
console.log( merge( "ab", "cd") );

// str1 is bigger, prints acbdx
console.log( merge( "abx", "cd") );

// str1 is bigger, prints acbdxy
console.log( merge( "abxy", "cd") );

// str2 is bigger, prints acbdx
console.log( merge( "ab", "cdx") );

// str2 is bigger, prints acbdxy
console.log( merge( "ab", "cdxy") );
```

Comment: Yeah thats a nice function. Scales with all the use cases I tested. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative using somewhat fewer comparisons in contrast to the other (current) answers.

```
function mergeStr( str1, str2 ) {
  let merged = "";
  const min = Math.min( str1.length, str2.length );

  // first part: take from both strings
  for( let i=0; i<min; i++ ) {
    merged += str1[i] + str2[i];
  }

  // second part: take the rest from either string
  let largerStr= str1.length > str2.length ? str1 : str2;
  merged += largerStr.substr( min );

  return merged;
}
```

This takes the shorter length and basically uses your approach for the first few characters. Afterwards, it just appends the rest of the larger string.

Comment: Good approach like in merge/quick sort when the values does not need to be swapped anymore ;)

Comment: This is a nice function. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I like one liners ..

```
function algo(str1,str2) {
    return Array.from(str1.length >= str2.length ? str1 : str2).map( (v,i) => (str1[i]||"")+(str2[i]||"") ).join("")
}
```

Comment: couldn't you use the index parameter of the `map()` callback instead of `i`?

Comment: trueeeeee hahaha

Answer (score 0):

How about finding the max length variable, then looping through it and if `undefined` fallback to a empty string.

```js
var a = 'ab';
var b = 'efg';

function mergeStr(a, b) {
  let newStr = '';
  let len = Math.max(a.length - 1, b.length - 1);
  for (let i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
    newStr += (a[i] || "") + (b[i] || "");
  }
  return newStr;
}

console.log(mergeStr(a, b));
```

Comment: You don't need to split and use `let` instead of `var` ;)